# How do I get started with the google io mission dashboard?

Tags: google-io-mission-dashboard

Google released a new online game at

https://events.google.com/io/mission/dashboard

And it appears as if the first step is determining the cluster name, but I can't figure out how to determine the cluster name.

I've tried typing in random strings found around the console, and pieces of various satellite properties, but I'm stuck.

I would prefer not just knowing the answer, but how I'm supposed to figure it out. Is there a help option I'm not reading? Is this supposed to be some deep hacking of the javascript (it appears to be sending data to a server to be validated, so I don't think source loading will help.)

Answer (score 1):

If you run the `help` command in the console on the page, it lists the available commands and gives some extra information about what you're trying to do. It gives this description of the mission:

> Discover the cluster names and set the satellites' frequencies. Make use of the  satellites' information to figure out the cluster names. You must first know the cluster name before setting the frequencies. Adjacent satellites must be set to different frequencies and all satellites must be assigned a frequency.

All of the satellite information together, plus the arrangement of the satellites, hints at what the cluster name is. In addition, at the bottom of the screen there are the numbers 01-06, each with a number of blanks. The cluster name fits in those blanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also found that they poorly explained how you find the cluster name. After giving up and looking it up, I realized the reason they don’t explain it well is because it makes the first puzzle rather easy. If you don’t want to look up answers and can’t figure it out, the name of the clusters is

> The shape the satellites make, as well as the names of the satellites being named after things that are related to the shape it makes

Comment: That is true of the first cluster, but not most of the others.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I see, I did not go past the first one so I just assumed.

Comment: It's more that that is part of the information that hints at what the answer is.

Comment: @murgatroid99 In your answer it says that the names and info of the satellites are clues, but the reason I did not include that is I could not see how they were hints.

Comment: In the first cluster, for example, each satellite name refers to a different object that is described by the cluster name.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I completely missed that, thanks.