# How are we supposed to figure out the names of all the clusters?

Tags: google-io-mission-dashboard

[The 9 to 5 article about the dashboard has the answers](https://9to5google.com/2020/01/23/google-io-2020-puzzle/), and I felt foolish after I had some initial difficulty with the first one, so I spent way too much time trying to figure out the next one before [giving up and asking an earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363411/how-do-i-get-started-with-the-google-io-mission-dashboard).

But all of the rest of them are basically impossible.

For the second one, the satellite information doesn't help at all and

> is a really just an obscure chemical where only the shape matters

For the third one, I don't know how anyone could figure it out:

> Except for maybe astronomers who are really good at knowing the shapes of all the constellations

The fourth one might be reasonable, but Wikipedia didn't have information about any of the ones I tried

The Fifth and sixth answers I'm quite familiar with, and I can't find *any* way to figure out how to figure them out.

Did google expect us to brute force the solutions somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get started with the google io mission dashboard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363411/how-do-i-get-started-with-the-google-io-mission-dashboard)

Comment: Note that that question is literally my question. The first question I asked, is "how can I figure out the first level?, This question is basically, "how can I figure out all (the rest) of them?"

Comment: McKay you could edit both this question and your previous question to make it clear that the first question is only for the 1st level and this is for subsequent levels. That's not clear currently.

Comment: @MBorg The previous question does state, in the title "get started". So I don't think that question needs more clarity. If you do, please help me understand why. I have updated the title of this question, and the opening paragraph of the this question to make it clear the it's talking about later levels.